# Visual Studio Post Build Script Equivalent for Java in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I was a C# developer in a .NET based product for a while and we used `Visual Studio` and post build scripts where provided to do whatever we want to do after we build.

Now I have moved on to Java world, and I am using `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2`. When I build project, it complies the java files into class files.

Now later I manually run a `jar -uvf` to update the jar file in the build. (Source and Build aren't directly linked.)

Is there anyway to configure the script I run in `IntelliJ`, so it automatically runs after I build?

Following are the links that proved helpless. Most people suggest ant, but the steps they provide simply are not present in `IntelliJ`, I guess it is due to version mismatch.

[Build-project-pre-and-post-actions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000720364-Build-project-pre-and-post-actions)

[How to run a script after building an artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233314/how-to-run-a-script-after-building-an-artifact)

[VS post build event command line equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802304/vs-post-build-event-command-line-equivalent-in-intellij-idea/5802458)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I researched, there is no off the shelf place to copy-paste your script, or link to script file in `IntelliJ` that could directly run scripts after building the project. So the following steps solves the purpose, but is not as ideal as solution in Visual Studio for .NET projects

Step 1

Put the jar update statements in a .sh file (for mac/linux) or .bat file (windows)

**updateJar.sh**

```sh
cd /path/to/classfiles/
jar -uvf /path/to/jar/file/x.jar package/stucture/
```

Step 2

Create an ant build file. The below execuatable and args are suitable for mac/linux systems. Please refer ant [docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) for exec and create correspondingly for windows.

**build.xml**

```xml
<project default="updateBuild">
    <target name="updateBuild">
        <exec executable="/bin/bash">
            <arg value="/path/to/updateJar.sh" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Step 3

Add the `build.xml` to `IntelliJ` project.

[image: Path to add build.xml]

For more details refer [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ant-build-tool-window.html).

Step 4

After adding the `build.xml`, right click the `updateBuild` target, **Select** `Execute On` and then **Select** `After Compilation`.

[image: Selecting post build timeline]

Voila. Now whenever you compile, your jar gets updated seamlessly. You can check output by expanding the target in the build messages tab.

[image: Output]